# How to setup pgx to get UTC values from DB?

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx, pq, ent

I'm using [Ent](https://github.com/ent/ent) with [Pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx).

The column created in Postgres is:

```sql
used_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
```

The value in Postgres is saved without timezone (in UTC):

```
2022-06-30 22:49:03.970913+00
```

Using this query:

```sql
show timezone
```

I get:

```
Etc/UTC
```

But from Ent (using `pgx` `stdlib`) I get the value:

```
2022-07-01T00:49:03.970913+02:00
```

Using `pgdriver`/`pq` I get the UTC value from DB.

How can I setup `pgx` to get UTC value?

I tried using this connection string with this code too:

```golang
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"
)

conn, err := sql.Open("pgx", "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/project?sslmode=disable&timezone=UTC")
//handle err
```

The problem is still here.

**I need a way to get back from DB the UTC values (that are laready stored in the DB).**

Comment: Next time please post a link to the relevant issue in the upstream project tracker or the comments you posted into it so that the next guy wanting to help won't discover it all by his/her own.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the data or the results `+00` **is** a timezone, or rather an offset, +00:00. The result is the exact same value in a different timezone and probably the result of client-side formatting. The driver wouldn't arbitrarily pick the Eastern European offset

Answer (score 4):

`timezone` is not a valid [*parameter key word*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS).

You can however use the [`options`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-OPTIONS) key word to specify command-line options to send to the server at connection start. Just keep in mind that you need to [percent encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) the values therein.

Example of how to set the [`TimeZone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE):

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    c1, err := pgx.Connect(ctx, "postgres:///?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer c1.Close(ctx)

    // sends "-c TimeZone=UTC" to server at connection start
    c2, err := pgx.Connect(ctx, "postgres:///?sslmode=disable&options=-c%20TimeZone%3DUTC")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer c2.Close(ctx)

    var tz1, tz2 string
    if err := c1.QueryRow(ctx, "SHOW timezone").Scan(&tz1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := c2.QueryRow(ctx, "SHOW timezone").Scan(&tz2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(tz1)
    fmt.Println(tz2)
}
```

```
Europe/Prague
UTC
```

However this only enforces the connection's timezone which does not seem to have an effect on how `pgx` parses the timestamps themselves once read from the database. In fact it seems it relies, directly or indirectly, on the host machine's local timezone. To confirm that you can update the global `time.Local` variable to UTC and observe the difference.

```golang
    // ...

    var t1, t2 time.Time
    if err := c1.QueryRow(ctx, "select now()::timestamptz").Scan(&t1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := c2.QueryRow(ctx, "select now()::timestamptz").Scan(&t2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t1)
    fmt.Println(t2)

    // explicitly set Local to UTC
    time.Local = time.UTC
    if err := c1.QueryRow(ctx, "select now()::timestamptz").Scan(&t1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := c2.QueryRow(ctx, "select now()::timestamptz").Scan(&t2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t1)
    fmt.Println(t2)
}
```

```
Europe/Prague
UTC
2022-06-27 17:18:13.189557 +0200 CEST
2022-06-27 17:18:13.190047 +0200 CEST
2022-06-27 15:18:13.190401 +0000 UTC
2022-06-27 15:18:13.190443 +0000 UTC
```

For obvious reasons I'd avoid doing the above. If `pgx` doesn't provide a way to configure the default location it uses to parse the timestamps then the next best option, that I can think of, would be to use a custom `time.Time` type.

```golang
    // ...

    var t1, t2 time.Time
    if err := c1.QueryRow(ctx, "select now()::timestamptz").Scan(&t1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := c2.QueryRow(ctx, "select now()::timestamptz").Scan(&t2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t1)
    fmt.Println(t2)

    var tt1, tt2 myTime
    if err := c1.QueryRow(ctx, "select now()::timestamptz").Scan(&tt1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := c2.QueryRow(ctx, "select now()::timestamptz").Scan(&tt2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(tt1)
    fmt.Println(tt2)
}

type myTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (tt *myTime) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    if t, ok := src.(time.Time); ok {
        tt.Time = t.In(time.UTC)
        return nil
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("myTime: unsupported type %T", src)
}
```

```
Europe/Prague
UTC
2022-06-27 17:26:45.94049 +0200 CEST
2022-06-27 17:26:45.940959 +0200 CEST
2022-06-27 15:26:45.941321 +0000 UTC
2022-06-27 15:26:45.941371 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: --- Thank you very much @mkopriva. Your hint is very useful only if I need to change the DB timezone. My DB is already on UTC. The issue is that pgx is returning time not in UTC format, but with `+02:00` at the end.

Comment: I tried with this too: `sql.Open("pgx", connURL+"&options=-c%20TimeZone%3DUTC")`. It's the same, not UTC values.

Comment: @FredHors I've added some updates.

Comment: More custom code, more issues! It's crazy pgx acts like that!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your application to use UTC globally:

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {

    location, _ := time.LoadLocation("UTC")
    time.Local = location
    
    // setup db connection
    // ...
}
```